# How to identify consecutive times with gap less than X seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a set of time stamps (SQL 2012) with a type I or O (input or output) like the sample data below:

[image]

I need to set the "**status**" column to INACTIVE to those consecutive times of the same type (Input or Output) where the gap between them is less than 120 seconds. The first time stamp in that consecutive group won't get any status.

In the image you can see how should it work.

I have about 80,0000 records that I have to analyze and set INACTIVE flag where the condition is matched. That should be done in a Stored Procedure.

**UPDATE** HERE IS THE SQL SCRIPT THAT CAN BE USED FOR TESTING

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c9e7/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this readily with `lag()` and some logic.  The `select` form of the query is:

```
select t.*,
       (case when datediff(second,
                           lag(TimeStamp) over (partition by EntranceType Order by TimeStamp),
                           TimeStamp) < 120
             then 'InActive'
        end) as NewColumnStatus
from timestamp_01 t;
```

If you want to do an update, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (case when datediff(second,
                                 lag(TimeStamp) over (partition by EntranceType Order by TimeStamp),
                                 TimeStamp) < 120
                   then 'InActive'
              end) as NewColumnStatus
      from timestamp_01 t
     )
update toupdate
    set Status = NewColumnStatus;
```

EDIT:

The `employee_id` should be easy to add:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (case when datediff(second,
                                 lag(TimeStamp) over (partition by employee_id, EntranceType Order by TimeStamp),
                                 TimeStamp) < 120
                   then 'InActive'
              end) as NewColumnStatus
      from timestamp_01 t
     )
update toupdate
    set Status = NewColumnStatus;
```

Comment: Seems to work!!, how about if I have an employee column so the rule applies by grouping by employee?

Comment: Wooow, that CTE is awesome... I have to learn CTE seems to be very very powerful :)

Comment: I can't use lag and lead in 2008. Is there a way to do this for SQL server 2008 ?

Comment: @Gordon thanks a lot I really apprecaite it. I will publish a new question with the EmployeeID column added to the table and let you know about the question. Im impressive about CTE

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev . . . The *question* explicitly says SQL Server 2012 (although it is tagged SQL Server 2008).  `lag()` is not available in 2008.  If you have a different question about 2008, then ask another question with sample data and so on.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks a lot!! incredible solution :)